# Migrate Workflow Manager 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, migration, database, workflow-manager

Anyone can provide an official article / good resource on how to migrate SharePoint 2013 workflows from one farm to another?

Comment: This might be your answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132524/move-workflow-manager-to-new-farm-in-a-new-domain